# More complex filterPredicate for NSArrayController

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, core-data, nstableview

I am using a `NSArrayController` which has a Managed Object Context to present data of a CoreData source in a `NSTableView`.
Everything works fine, I can also use `filterPredicate` to filter my results which also reflect in the `NSTableView`.
For example

```
coreDataArrayController.filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "dataType == %@","live_data")
```

shows only the rows with this specific value "live_data" in the "dataType" attribute.

I do have some binary data in the CoreData database which I can parse using custom functions. Is there a way I can filter using this information too?
For example I have an attribute "binary_data" which contains binary representation of a `NSImage`. I now want to check the image type of this `NSImage` and use this information to filter my dataset.

Something like:

```
coreDataArrayController.filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "imageType(binary_data) == %@,"png")
```

To show only rows that contain an image in "binary_data" that is a png (which is checked by my custom function "imageType"

Comment: Use a calculated property or a `NSPredicate` with a block.

Comment: Wasn't aware that calculated property was so simple so this looks like the easiest solution here